# what is the Alternative Way of TabActivity?

Tags: android-fragmentactivity

Hi I want to use Tab Activity(My Tab View must be at bottom) and android version 4.0 or later told that tabactivity is deprecated. so it must be a better way than it. but I could not find properly. some tutorials gave me advise to use Fragments but really I don't know anything about it. so please suggest me best tutorial or sample code for Fragments Or other best alternative way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion is to use the Sherlock ActionBar. Inside the package there are good sample projects about Fragments, ActionBar, Navigation with tabs! I recommend [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)!
It also is 2.x compatible!!!

Comment: If the need is only for Tab bar , then i dont think so he need ActionBarSherlock library to be included. Also it is not a light weight library too.

Answer (score 0):

here is a link from android developer site,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

and a tutorial,

http://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/

Just by following above links you can create i easily.